# CSS 3 Rotate Animation on hover

Tags: html, css

I have this code to make a rotation on hover. It doesn't work at all. What's is wrong with it?

**I need the complete animation of the rotation for 360º**

```css
.icon-style-1 .builder-element-icon {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    background: blue;
    line-height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: white;
}    

.icon-style-1 .builder-element-icon:hover {
    background: green;
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="icon-style-1">
    <span class="builder-element-icon fa fa-camera"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: provide some `html` too

Comment: I just edited title and add some text to my question

Comment: BTW, you should change `class=".icon-style-1"` to `class="icon-style-1"`

Answer (score 2):

360 degrees rotates it back to its original place. you probably wanted it to be 180deg;

if you want it animatad, you need to add a `transition`:

```css
.icon-style-1 .builder-element-icon{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: white;

  -moz-transition: -moz-transform ease 0.6s;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform ease 0.6s;
  -o-transition: -o-transform ease 0.6s;
  -ms-transition: -ms-transform ease 0.6s;
  transition: transform ease 0.6s;
}    

.icon-style-1 .builder-element-icon:hover{
    background: green;
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);

}
```

```html
<div class="icon-style-1">
<span class="builder-element-icon fa fa-camera">a</span>
</div>
```

and in case you want to animate the background color to, you could replace `transition: transform ease 0.6s;` withe either

```
transition: transform ease 0.6s, background ease 0.6s;
```

or

```
transition: all ease 0.6s;
```

Comment: but I need the complete animation of the rotation for 360º

Comment: so you should add a transition property…

Comment: ok, I just edited title and add some text to my question.

Comment: added it in my answer

Comment: Not working in my code, I will check the html.

Comment: as I commented to the question, you have an extra point in your class in the html

Comment: was a typo just a mistake

Comment: Not working in my code; this is the real html '<div id="builder-content-icon-1" class="builder-content-icon-wrapper icon-style-1 hvr-float"><div class="builder-content-icon-inner builder-content-icon-size-xl"><span class="builder-element-icon fa fa-camera"></span></div></div>' https://jsfiddle.net/r9vz9mht/

Answer (score 2):

So here you go with `transition` on normal element style and rotate added on `hover` and **[External DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/1m23cut6/2/)**

```css
.icon-style-1 .builder-element-icon{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    background: blue;
    line-height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: white;
   /* Firefox */
 -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
 /* WebKit */
 -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
 /* Opera */
 -o-transition: all 1s ease;
 /* Standard */
 transition: all 1s ease;
}    

.icon-style-1 .builder-element-icon:hover{
    background: green;
    /* Firefox */
 -moz-transform: rotate(360deg) ;
 /* WebKit */
 -webkit-transform:  rotate(360deg);
 /* Opera */
 -o-transform: rotate(360deg) ;
 /* Standard */
 transform: rotate(360deg) ;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="icon-style-1">
    <div class="builder-element-icon glyphicon glyphicon-camera">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not working in my code; this is the real html '<div id="builder-content-icon-1" class="builder-content-icon-wrapper icon-style-1 hvr-float"><div class="builder-content-icon-inner builder-content-icon-size-xl"><span class="builder-element-icon fa fa-camera"></span></div></div>' https://jsfiddle.net/r9vz9mht/

Comment: @JPashs - here **[demo with your html](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/1m23cut6/3/)**

Comment: Only works in Safari. Not working in Chrome and Firefox v40

Comment: @JPashs.. I do not have `safari` here and I gave solution after testing in chrome itself.. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS3 transitions in order to achieve this result.

Just move your mouse over the label.

```css
#rotatable {
    font-size: 30px;
}

#rotatable:hover {
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<span id="rotatable">I can rotate!</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add [CSS Transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions). Also, you don't need to use `-moz`, `-ms` and `-o` vendor prefixes now, see [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#search=transitions):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/aovab8u0/1/)

```css
.icon-style-1 .builder-element-icon {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    background: blue;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: white;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}    

.icon-style-1 .builder-element-icon:hover {
    background: green;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="icon-style-1">
    <span class="builder-element-icon fa fa-camera"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: working , but it flip the element, I need rotation.

Comment: @JPashs try now please, I took your code and fixed it.

Comment: @JPashs I looked into other answers comments, [JSFiddle with your real HTML](http://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/Lxjyj5cb/).